# Best book with several annotated games by top GMs with the Dutch

Tags: books, master-games, dutch-defense

I'm looking for annotated games by top GMs featuring the Dutch defense.  These could be in a book with lots of other non-Dutch games.  Unfortunately Botvinnik's ["Botvinnik: One Hundred Selected Games"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486206203) as I recall doesn't have quite a half dozen and they are all Stonewalls: I'd like some "Classical" variation games too.  How about ["Zurich International Chess Tournament, 1953"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486238008); Bronstein played the Dutch, didn't he?  Unfortunately with Amazon's "search inside" feature it doesn't look like the games were indexed by opening.  As you can tell I don't mind if the games are old-ish (and this will weed out lots of Leningrad Dutch's I'm not necessarily interested in at this point), though I'm also open to more recent games too.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the collections of Larsen's games perhaps?  Again though I can't see the indices of the pertinent books on amazon.  Guess there would be some very recent games by Nakamura but I believe he is playing the Leningrad variation

Answer (score 3):

The [World Championship Match between Botvinnik and Bronstein in 1951](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?tid=54195) contains quite a number of Dutch Defense games. I didn't find many books about the match, but there was [one by Botvinnik](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3283004595) that may provide a good reference point.

Answer (score 2):

[The Killer Dutch](https://www.gingergm.com/shop/killer-dutch-the-book-ebook) by GM Simon Williams includes 24 annotated games, as well as a lot of great advice and new ideas for Dutch players. It focuses mainly on the Classical Dutch, so it sounds ideal for you.

[image: The Killer Dutch by Simon Williams]

There's also an accompanying DVD that's very decent, available [from Simon's own site here](http://www.gingergm.com/shop/killer-dutch) or as a [digital download from OCL](https://www.ichess.net/shop/dutch-defense-gm-simon-williams/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out on chessgames.com: for ECO A91 dutch defense:

http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessopening?eco=A91

Comment: Are the games annotated by GMs, though?